# jQuery Multiple File Uploader (mfupload.js) not working in frame

Tags: jquery-plugins

Great app! One problem, it does not seem to work inside a frame. The exact same code outside a frame does work. And by work I mean it does not initialize and display the "ini_text", (Drag files here or click to upload), and clicking on the upload region does nothing. Any thoughts?

Comment: yaaaaaaaa i do it .... by doing comment in mfupload.js by commenting line no. 158 by removing condition if ( !((window.location != window.parent.location) ? true : false) )

Answer (score 0):

find `!((window.location != window.parent.location) ? true : false)` change to `!((window.location == window.parent.location) ? true : false)`